# Handle any error Nodejs and don't return a stack trace

Tags: node.js, error-handling

The question is simple, but I cannot find a solution that will work when tested against [Passport](http://passportjs.org/).

Let's say I have a callback route like `https://localhost/auth/google/callback`

Right now I'm getting a stack trace if I throw garbage parameters here that then shows information like directory structures, etc, which is obviously not appropriate. I cannot blindly depend on every new route to handle errors appropriately.

Is there any way for me to disable a stack trace response given ANY error in NodeJS?

I tried the following:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => { 
    if (! err) {
        return next();
    }    

    res.status(500);
    res.send('500: Internal server error');
});
```

And this did not work for `TokenError: Code was already redeemed.` used in PassportJS.

Is this even possible? Obviously this would be for a production environment only.

Comment: FYI, if you set the environment variable `NODE_ENV=production`, then the stack trace will not be included in the built-in error handler.  Source of that info here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html.  Other than that, the error handler you show should work if implemented properly though you don't need to check for `if (!err)` because this middleware won't get called unless there is an error.

Comment: Similar question from same author: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047243/passport-authenticate-error-handling-passport-js.  Probably don't need both of these.

Comment: I deleted the other one.

Answer (score 11):

You need to set NODE_ENV to production to disable stacktrace, you can change it as an enviroment variable.

`set NODE_ENV=production`

Or if it's inconvenient do it in the program itself like this:

```js
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
```